# Fetching Data from the related tables NHibernate mysql

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, criteria

I have 3 tables in mysql

### **User**

`id` (auto increment)(PK)
`user_name`
`password`
`first_name`
`last_name`
`created_at`
`modified_at`
`email`

### User_Role

`user_id` (PK)
`role_id` (PK)

### Role

`id`(PK)
`name`

The Mapping file User.hbm.xml

The Mapping file User_Role.hbm.xml

The Mapping file Role.hbm.xml

```
<id name="RoleId" column="id">
  <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
<property name="Name" column="name"  length="64"/>
```

I want to fetch the information from these tables with the query

SELECT u.*,r.name 
FROM user u
JOIN user_role ur ON UR.user_id=u.id
JOIN role r on UR.role_id=r.id

I tried with this code
ICriteria Criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User));
                Criteria.CreateAlias("User_Role", "User_Role");
                Criteria.CreateAlias("User_Role.Role", "UsrRole");
                Criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("id", Uid));
but its showing error 
can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Relations with between entities are done with mapping, not with queries. You might like to read some minimal documentation.